# Tweets don’t load

Tags: twitter

Twitter says I have some ~1.000 tweets, but I can’t load/see them, neither on the website, nor through the desktop app—it stays in the “loading” state forever. And they don’t appear in the downloaded archive either. Why does this happen and how can I overcome it?

[image]

I should mention that these are some two years old tweets and that this has happened for quite some time now (months).

Comment: This looks like a bug on Twitter's side, your best solution is to contact them.

Comment: Did you get any information from Twitter regarding this?

Comment: No, none whatsoever.

Comment: I think it's a twitter issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time i too gets the same issue. But this seems to be browser related issue because for slow connection they show message like "Loading seems to be slow.Please wait".
They have certain limits for tweeting etc.so there may some rule applicable to listing of tweets too. But however, there is way to get archive in the account.

Comment: No, they don’t appear in the downloaded archive either.